# Find mongodb docs based on array of object contains two fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Example: `Mongo db collection:`

```
[
  {
    "user_id": 1,
    "lead_id": 901,
     ...
     ...
  },
  {
    "user_id": 2,
    "lead_id": 902,
     ...
     ...
  },
   {
    "user_id": 2,
    "lead_id": 903,
    ...
    ...
  },
 {
    "user_id": 3,
    "lead_id": 999,
    ...
    ...
  },
]
```

I have an array of objects:

```
const reqArr = [
  {
    "user_id": 1,
    "lead_id": 901,
  }, 
   {
    "user_id": 2,
    "lead_id": 999,
   }
]
```

I want to query the DB based on both `user_id` and `lead_id` present in each object in the array `reqArr`. something like this or with aggregate pipeline

```
Model.find(reqArr)
```

My desired output would be something like this:

```
[{
 "user_id": 1,
 "lead_id": 901,
  ...
  ...
}]
```

I only know how to query based on the array of one field like `Model.find({_id: {"$in": [array of ids ]}})` but not with more than one field in an array of object.
Any idea or workaround to achieve something like the above output or negation of the above output? I only need which objects in `reqArr` are present in db collection or which are not. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple `$or`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {
          "user_id": 1,
          "lead_id": 901
        },
        {
          "user_id": 2,
          "lead_id": 902
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/btFxhpLBW_1)

---

node

```
const reqArr = [
  {
    "user_id": 1,
    "lead_id": 901,
  }, 
   {
    "user_id": 2,
    "lead_id": 999,
   }
]
Model.find({ "$or": reqArr})
```

Comment: oh my gosh....how could I forget about $or operator.....

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do the above would be this:

```js
const results = await Promise.all(reqArr.map(req => {
    const { user_id, lead_id } = req;
    return Model.findOne({ user_id, lead_id });
}));
```

We map over each item in `reqArr`. For each item (`req`), we destructure into two variables `user_id` and `lead_id`.

We then query for a single document (I assume there is only one document for each `user_id` and `lead_id` pair, otherwise this will need to be slightly adjusted.

We then return the `findOne` promise, resulting in an array of promises which we pass into `Promise.all` to await them all asynchronously.

This should result flat array of results that match the `lead_iq`/`user_id` pairs in `reqArr`.

If some of these combos aren't present in the database, those elements of the array will be `undefined` and you can go on to handle those however you need to.

Comment: the issue with mapping over all objects and fetching db results is, it will definitely increase the memory footprint in the server, Not good for a production server. If we map over a huge array of objects and fetch results in the server, it will eventually crash. We should always delegate the job to DB like @YuTing's answer

Comment: Of course, which is why I said this is the simplest solution. I got that impression that this was someone learning, not trying to write production code.